# Could anybody explain me the independence in bayesian nets?

Tags: probability, bayesian, bayesian-networks, probability-theory

Could anybody explain me conditional independence in the following cases? Could you give me any other appropriate examples for each case?[image]

Answer (score 1):

**First** and **third** examples fall under rule, that says if a variable's all parents are known, it should care only about its children and it is conditionally independent of all other variables.

In the **first** example the random variable `JohnCalls`(child) is conditionally independent of the random variable `Burglary`(grandpa), which means that, if we know the state of random variable `Alarm`(parent), `Johncalls` will act accordingly regardless whether there was a `Burglary` or not.

The similar example would be `WasPartying -> HomeworkWasntCompleted -> ReceivedBadGrade`. Here, regardless whether you were partying or not, if homework wasn't completed (the parent is known), you gonna receive bad grade. So if we have a value of `HomeworkWasntCompleted`, learning value of `WasPartying` doesn't give us any new information about `ReceivedBadGrade`.

In the **third** example it's the same: if we know that `Alarm` is on, `Marycalls` won't give us any new hint about `JohnCalls`, so `JohnCalls` is conditionally independent of `MaryCalls` given the value of `Alarm`.

The **second** example is a little bit trickier. Although we know all the parents of `Burglary` (obviously, cause it doesn't have any parents), we **can't** say that `Burglary` is conditionally independent of `Earthquake`. Cause if we know that `Alarm` is on, and we received an information about `Earthquake`, we would guess that the `Alarm` was triggered by `Earthquake` and the chances of `Burglary` is considerably lower. So, in this case `Earthquake` gives us some information about `Burglary`. This example doesn't fall under the rule described above, cause the variables questioned upon conditional independence share the same descendant.

The similar example would be `WasPartying -> HomeworkWasntCompleted <- DidntUnderstandTopic` (pay attention to arrow directions).

[Here you can find a nice lecture about conditional independence.](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~awm/15781/slides/bayesinf05a.pdf)